# gcloud command output formatting to use results in another gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to automate the deletion of SSL certificates that end with a certain text pattern on GCP projects.

For this I use the command:

```
 gcloud compute ssl-certificates list --filter="name~'819$'" --format="(name)"
```

Which output displays exactly this format:

```
NAME
certname1-1602160819
certname2-1602160819
certname3-1602160819
...and so on
```

The thing is that if I want to use the results from this command to then use it to input another `gcloud` command that deletes each certificate, I get the first variable as NAME which is the field title and obviously not a certificate.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for oldcert in $( gcloud compute ssl-certificates list --filter="name~'819$'" --format="(NAME)")
do
    gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete $oldcert
done
```

Do you know how I could get the field name NAME out of my output so I could treat each result in another command directly.

Thanks for your precious advices

Comment: You can use tail. e.g. `for oldcert in $(gcloud ... list | tail -n +2)`

Comment: There also seems to be no-heading format specifier, e.g. `csv[no-heading](name)`

Answer (score 4):

The right format to use is `--format="value[](name)"`.

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats#value):

> `value`
>
> CSV with no heading and <TAB> separator instead of <COMMA>. Used
> to retrieve individual resource values.

So it's equivalent to the `--format="csv[no-heading](name)"` that you used, but "*more correct*" (and a little more legible).

Answer (score 2):

@Hitobat thanks very much for your comment

I used the csv[no-heading] option even though the tails -n +2 otion also does the job

the following commands did the job great:

```
#!/bin/bash
for oldcert in $( gcloud compute ssl-certificates list --filter="name~'819$'" --format="csv[no-heading](name)")
do
    gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete $oldcert --quiet
done
```